# mysql IN query problem

Tags: mysql

```
select docid  from A  where  docid IN ( select distinct(docid) from B)
```

When I execute above query in mysql it takes **33** seconds, which is too long as per the size of data.

Below is the details of both tables.

```
   Table A :
   | docid       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   Total number of entries = 500 (all entries are unique)

   Table B:
   | docid       | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
   Total number of entries = 66508
   (number of unique entries are 500)

   mysql version : 5.2
```

If I execute only `select docid  from A` it will take 0.00 seconds,
while `select docid from B` is taking 0.07 seconds.

Then why IN query with subquery takes 33 seconds? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that query?

Comment: I am expecting this query should be executed in a second. then why this is taking too much time?

Comment: `desc select docid  from A  where  docid IN ( select distinct(docid) from B);` -- the overhead is because of the number rows require to scan in order to match the `IN()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't handle IN (subquery) well.  It executes the inner query every single time the outer query is evaluated, rather than "remembering" the results.

Hence you are much better doing a join.

Other RDBMSes don't do this btw.

Comment: Thanks Brian, to give me a this much of clarity.

Answer (score 6):

The `IN` list is very large - 60K entries. You would be better to use a join:

```
select A.docid -- edited - I left out the A. :(
from A
join B on B.docid = A.docid;
```

This should execute very quickly and will give you the same result as your "IN" query.

Comment: you need to put in the alias for `select docid` like `select A.docid`

Comment: Bohenian, i have edited my question because i used distinct in that query. when i execute "select distinct(docid) from B " it is taking 0.07 seconds only, then why it takes 33 seconds with IN query?

Comment: ... because the separate queries can use the primary key index to find the matching rows but the subquery might get executed like a "for loop" where every matching row in the subquery from B is matched against A. The JOIN is more effectively optimised in MySQL at the moment, e.g. see http://technocation.org/content/oursql-episode-29%3A-subpar-subqueries and the MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-subqueries.html